# Merge two tsv files on a key value removing columns that don't have all fields

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to merge two TSV columns on a common key. Lets say file A is:

```
a   100
b   200
c   300
```

and File B is:

```
a   "hello"
c   "my name is"
```

I want the output file to look like:

```
a   100 "Hello"
c   300 "my name is"
```

So far, I have created a file that looks like this:

```
a   100 "Hello"
b   200 ""
c   300 "my name is"
```

I want to remove the extra unneeded row because it doesn't possess all the fields.

Here is the code I have thus far

```
 awk '
 NR==1{print "column_A","column_B","column_C"}

 FNR==NR{
          A[$1]=$2
          next 
        }
       {
            print $0,( f=$1 in A ? A[$1] : "" )
            if(f) delete A[$1]
        }
     END{
           for(i in A)
               print i,"",A[i]
        }
' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

Is there any way of doing a slight modification on this code to get that output?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `join` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command:

```
join -t$'\t' file1 file2
```

Note that this requires that the input files be sorted on the joining field. If they aren't, you can use process substitution.

```
join -t$'\t' <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1) <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file2)
```

Comment: Oh my,  that looks so much easier! Thank you!